# JVM garbage collection in JDK 11

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I am trying to understand the GC in JVM, and write a piece of code as following. However, when I change the sleep from 1s to 5s, there will be OOM error. I really don't know why.
Additionally, the reason I sleep the main thread is that I try to make the main thread wait for a while until the GC thread finished the work.

```
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;

/**
 * -Xmx20M to set the max heap to 20M
 */
public class ApplySoftReference {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SoftReference<byte[]> softReference = new SoftReference<>(new byte[1024*1024*10]);
        System.out.println(softReference.get());
        // suggest to run gc thread,
        // however if the usable memory on heap is enough, gc will not run
        System.gc();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // still can get the reference of the byte[]
        System.out.println(softReference.get());

        // create a normal reference, since set the memory for heap to 20M,
        // gc thread will recollect the memory space from the SoftReference,
        // then provide memory space to the following normal reference
        byte[] b = new byte[1024*1024*15];
        System.out.println(softReference.get());
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Here is my gc output for when out of memory:

```
    [0.078s][info][gc,heap] Heap region size: 1M
[0.079s][info][gc     ] Using G1
[0.079s][info][gc,heap,coops] Heap address: 0x00000007fec00000, size: 20 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
[0.211s][info][gc,start     ] GC(0) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation)
[0.211s][info][gc,task      ] GC(0) Using 2 workers of 8 for evacuation
[0.213s][info][gc,phases    ] GC(0)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.0ms
[0.213s][info][gc,phases    ] GC(0)   Evacuate Collection Set: 1.7ms
[0.213s][info][gc,phases    ] GC(0)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[0.213s][info][gc,phases    ] GC(0)   Other: 0.4ms
[0.213s][info][gc,heap      ] GC(0) Eden regions: 2->0(11)
[0.213s][info][gc,heap      ] GC(0) Survivor regions: 0->1(2)
[0.213s][info][gc,heap      ] GC(0) Old regions: 0->0
[0.213s][info][gc,heap      ] GC(0) Humongous regions: 0->0
[0.213s][info][gc,metaspace ] GC(0) Metaspace: 6167K->6167K(1056768K)
[0.213s][info][gc           ] GC(0) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation) 2M->0M(20M) 2.175ms
[0.213s][info][gc,cpu       ] GC(0) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[0.213s][info][gc           ] GC(1) Concurrent Cycle
[0.213s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(1) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks
[0.213s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(1) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks 0.008ms
[0.213s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(1) Concurrent Scan Root Regions
[0.214s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(1) Concurrent Scan Root Regions 0.849ms
[0.214s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(1) Concurrent Mark (0.214s)
[0.214s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(1) Concurrent Mark From Roots
[0.214s][info][gc,task      ] GC(1) Using 2 workers of 2 for marking
[0.214s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(1) Concurrent Mark From Roots 0.113ms
[0.214s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(1) Concurrent Preclean
[0.214s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(1) Concurrent Preclean 0.031ms
[0.214s][info][gc,marking   ] GC(1) Concurrent Mark (0.214s, 0.214s) 0.165ms
[0.220s][info][gc,start     ] GC(1) Pause Remark
[0.221s][info][gc,stringtable] GC(1) Cleaned string and symbol table, strings: 2591 processed, 0 removed, symbols: 25907 processed, 0 removed
[0.221s][info][gc            ] GC(1) Pause Remark 11M->11M(20M) 0.793ms
[0.221s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(1) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[0.221s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(1) Concurrent Rebuild Remembered Sets
[0.221s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(1) Concurrent Rebuild Remembered Sets 0.042ms
[0.221s][info][gc,start      ] GC(1) Pause Cleanup
[0.222s][info][gc            ] GC(1) Pause Cleanup 12M->12M(20M) 0.026ms
[0.222s][info][gc,cpu        ] GC(1) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[0.222s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(1) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark
[0.222s][info][gc,marking    ] GC(1) Concurrent Cleanup for Next Mark 0.252ms
[0.222s][info][gc            ] GC(1) Concurrent Cycle 8.421ms
[B@6b71769e
[0.222s][info][gc,task       ] GC(2) Using 2 workers of 8 for full compaction
[0.222s][info][gc,start      ] GC(2) Pause Full (System.gc())
[0.222s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(2) Phase 1: Mark live objects
[0.224s][info][gc,stringtable ] GC(2) Cleaned string and symbol table, strings: 2601 processed, 3 removed, symbols: 25926 processed, 0 removed
[0.224s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(2) Phase 1: Mark live objects 1.435ms
[0.224s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(2) Phase 2: Prepare for compaction
[0.224s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(2) Phase 2: Prepare for compaction 0.361ms
[0.224s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(2) Phase 3: Adjust pointers
[0.225s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(2) Phase 3: Adjust pointers 0.757ms
[0.225s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(2) Phase 4: Compact heap
[0.226s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(2) Phase 4: Compact heap 0.981ms
[0.226s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(2) Eden regions: 1->0(3)
[0.226s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(2) Survivor regions: 1->0(2)
[0.226s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(2) Old regions: 0->2
[0.226s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(2) Humongous regions: 11->11
[0.226s][info][gc,metaspace   ] GC(2) Metaspace: 6205K->6205K(1056768K)
[0.226s][info][gc             ] GC(2) Pause Full (System.gc()) 12M->11M(20M) 3.862ms
[0.226s][info][gc,cpu         ] GC(2) User=0.01s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s
[B@6b71769e
[5.228s][info][gc,start       ] GC(3) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation)
[5.228s][info][gc,task        ] GC(3) Using 2 workers of 8 for evacuation
[5.230s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(3)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.0ms
[5.230s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(3)   Evacuate Collection Set: 1.5ms
[5.230s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(3)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[5.230s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(3)   Other: 0.2ms
[5.230s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(3) Eden regions: 1->0(3)
[5.230s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(3) Survivor regions: 0->1(1)
[5.230s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(3) Old regions: 2->2
[5.230s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(3) Humongous regions: 11->11
[5.230s][info][gc,metaspace   ] GC(3) Metaspace: 7416K->7416K(1056768K)
[5.230s][info][gc             ] GC(3) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Humongous Allocation) 12M->12M(20M) 1.907ms
[5.230s][info][gc,cpu         ] GC(3) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[5.230s][info][gc             ] GC(4) Concurrent Cycle
[5.230s][info][gc,marking     ] GC(4) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks
[5.230s][info][gc,marking     ] GC(4) Concurrent Clear Claimed Marks 0.023ms
[5.230s][info][gc,marking     ] GC(4) Concurrent Scan Root Regions
[5.231s][info][gc,marking     ] GC(4) Concurrent Scan Root Regions 0.571ms
[5.231s][info][gc,marking     ] GC(4) Concurrent Mark (5.231s)
[5.231s][info][gc,marking     ] GC(4) Concurrent Mark From Roots
[5.231s][info][gc,task        ] GC(4) Using 2 workers of 2 for marking
[5.231s][info][gc,start       ] GC(5) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Humongous Allocation)
[5.231s][info][gc,task        ] GC(5) Using 2 workers of 8 for evacuation
[5.232s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(5)   Pre Evacuate Collection Set: 0.6ms
[5.232s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(5)   Evacuate Collection Set: 1.0ms
[5.232s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(5)   Post Evacuate Collection Set: 0.1ms
[5.232s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(5)   Other: 0.1ms
[5.232s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Eden regions: 0->0(3)
[5.232s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Survivor regions: 1->1(1)
[5.232s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Old regions: 2->2
[5.232s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(5) Humongous regions: 11->11
[5.232s][info][gc,metaspace   ] GC(5) Metaspace: 7416K->7416K(1056768K)
[5.232s][info][gc             ] GC(5) Pause Young (Normal) (G1 Humongous Allocation) 12M->12M(20M) 1.213ms
[5.232s][info][gc,cpu         ] GC(5) User=0.01s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[5.232s][info][gc,task        ] GC(6) Using 2 workers of 8 for full compaction
[5.232s][info][gc,start       ] GC(6) Pause Full (G1 Humongous Allocation)
[5.232s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(6) Phase 1: Mark live objects
[5.234s][info][gc,stringtable ] GC(6) Cleaned string and symbol table, strings: 4931 processed, 1 removed, symbols: 31411 processed, 1 removed
[5.234s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(6) Phase 1: Mark live objects 1.988ms
[5.234s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(6) Phase 2: Prepare for compaction
[5.234s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(6) Phase 2: Prepare for compaction 0.359ms
[5.234s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(6) Phase 3: Adjust pointers
[5.235s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(6) Phase 3: Adjust pointers 0.758ms
[5.235s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(6) Phase 4: Compact heap
[5.236s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(6) Phase 4: Compact heap 0.668ms
[5.236s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(6) Eden regions: 0->0(4)
[5.236s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(6) Survivor regions: 1->0(1)
[5.236s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(6) Old regions: 2->2
[5.236s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(6) Humongous regions: 11->11
[5.236s][info][gc,metaspace   ] GC(6) Metaspace: 7416K->7416K(1056768K)
[5.236s][info][gc             ] GC(6) Pause Full (G1 Humongous Allocation) 12M->12M(20M) 4.187ms
[5.236s][info][gc,cpu         ] GC(6) User=0.00s Sys=0.00s Real=0.01s
[5.236s][info][gc,task        ] GC(7) Using 2 workers of 8 for full compaction
[5.236s][info][gc,start       ] GC(7) Pause Full (G1 Humongous Allocation)
[5.236s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(7) Phase 1: Mark live objects
[5.238s][info][gc,stringtable ] GC(7) Cleaned string and symbol table, strings: 4930 processed, 5 removed, symbols: 31410 processed, 0 removed
[5.238s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(7) Phase 1: Mark live objects 1.540ms
[5.238s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(7) Phase 2: Prepare for compaction
[5.238s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(7) Phase 2: Prepare for compaction 0.303ms
[5.238s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(7) Phase 3: Adjust pointers
[5.239s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(7) Phase 3: Adjust pointers 0.626ms
[5.239s][info][gc,phases,start] GC(7) Phase 4: Compact heap
[5.239s][info][gc,phases      ] GC(7) Phase 4: Compact heap 0.389ms
[5.240s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(7) Eden regions: 0->0(4)
[5.240s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(7) Survivor regions: 0->0(1)
[5.240s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(7) Old regions: 2->2
[5.240s][info][gc,heap        ] GC(7) Humongous regions: 11->0
[5.240s][info][gc,metaspace   ] GC(7) Metaspace: 7416K->7416K(1056768K)
[5.240s][info][gc             ] GC(7) Pause Full (G1 Humongous Allocation) 12M->1M(8M) 3.496ms
[5.240s][info][gc,cpu         ] GC(7) User=0.01s Sys=0.00s Real=0.00s
[5.240s][info][gc,marking     ] GC(4) Concurrent Mark From Roots 9.200ms
[5.240s][info][gc,marking     ] GC(4) Concurrent Mark Abort
[5.240s][info][gc             ] GC(4) Concurrent Cycle 9.875ms
[5.241s][info][gc,heap,exit   ] Heap
[5.241s][info][gc,heap,exit   ]  garbage-first heap   total 20480K, used 1214K [0x00000007fec00000, 0x0000000800000000)
[5.241s][info][gc,heap,exit   ]   region size 1024K, 1 young (1024K), 0 survivors (0K)
[5.241s][info][gc,heap,exit   ]  Metaspace       used 7431K, capacity 7524K, committed 7680K, reserved 1056768K
[5.241s][info][gc,heap,exit   ]   class space    used 660K, capacity 673K, committed 768K, reserved 1048576K
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at Thread.c_004.ApplySoftReference.main(ApplySoftReference.java:26)
```

Comment: yes, I mean Out Of Memory error.

Comment: There are related bug reports, [JDK-8215232, Make soft reference reclamation more aggressive during concurrent marking](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8215232) and [JDK-8014364, SoftReference clearing needs to improve when memory is constrained](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8014364). There seem to be a bad interaction between `-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB` and concurrent garbage collection (G1GC) but I couldn’t find out, how it affects this example exactly. The results seem somewhat random, the sleep time only changing the likelihood.